# Run an Application form Powershell with Credentials

Tags: powershell, passwords, autofill

I am using the `Invoke-Item` command to start an application. When I run it, it prompts for username and password. I want to auto fill that through `PowerShell`, can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

You can you the `[-Credential <PSCredential>]` parameter with a `PSCredential object` to do this:

```
# Edit your creds here
$user = "Domain\Username"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "MyPassword" -AsPlainText -Force

$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($user, $password)
Invoke-Item "Your Application" -Credential $mycreds
```